# Flutter Form from REST API JSON for offline use

Tags: json, forms, api, flutter, offline

I need to do something like this using Flutter and I have no idea how to do it or even where to look for clues so I will appreciate any help.

1. Flutter app gets JSON data from REST API
2. Data is written into local storage for offline use
3. Based on that data a form is generated
4. When the remote data on the server changes, new version swaps the old one in local storage
5. New form is generated and usable in offline mode

any idea?

Comment: 1. for HTTP  requests - https://pub.dev/packages/http, super easy to use. 2. Database - https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite, if there's not to much data from the server you can save it on shared preferences (https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences). The rest is only logic.

Comment: I know how to get the data from the API. What I don't know and I can't find any useful info about is how to generate dynamic (hopefully in most efficient way) form based of that data so that it can be used offline

Comment: Seems like I have found something useful at last :) https://flutterawesome.com/flutter-libraries-allowing-you-to-consume-complex-external-forms-at-runtime/